# Using extra in django querystet combined with django lookups (not constant parameters in extra)

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I want to call a postgresql function in django queryset and parameters of this function are related to current row.

Lets assume I have following queryset:

```
queryset = Baz.objects.filter(foo = 'foo', foo__bar = 'bar').
```

and I would like to add an extra argument that calls a function, and argument of this function should be name that django lookup `foo_baz` resolves to.

In ideal world i would like to write:

```
queryset.extra(were = "my_function(foo__baz)")
```

that woul render to:

```
my_function("FOO_TABLE".baz)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is response for this problem from django developers:

> `extra` often creates more problem than it solves. The current trend is to
>    deprecate it rather than extend it.
>
> The recommended way to achieve your goal is to use raw SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You reference columns like this with [F() objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model) generally, but I'm not sure if you can use them with `extra()` in a case like this. Hopefully that's a starting point for you to experiment though.